# Изменение размеров View

Tags: android, android-layout

Есть View, под которым находится тулбар с кнопками и текстовым полем. Нужно, чтобы он динамически масштабировался при открывании клавиатуры и других панелей, находящихся выше или ниже этого View.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Он называется SnappingRecyclerView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    tools:context=".activity.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/show_camera"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#f4f5f7">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_camera"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:background="#f4f5f7"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/camera59" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_mic"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:background="#f4f5f7"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/microphone_black" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_cat"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btn_mic"
                android:background="#f4f5f7"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/square234" />

            <com.superup.smartshelf.utils.ClearableAutoComplete
                android:id="@+id/autocomplete"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btn_cat"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btn_camera"
                android:background="@drawable/round_rect_shape"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:singleLine="true" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <SurfaceView
            android:id="@+id/camera_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:visibility="gone" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <com.superup.smartshelf.view.SnappingRecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/item_list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/show_camera" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Activity может взаимодействовать с экранной клавиатурой, там есть несколько параметров и один из них именно resize. Добавьте в манифест к тому активити, с которой хотите наладить этот контакт:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
```

Comment: В этом случае у меня автоматически открывается клавиатура. Поэтому я использую `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"`. Но результата это все равно не дает. View не масштабируется, а поднимается и обрезается сверху и снизу

Comment: можете подсказать, как добавить анимацию на уменьшение view, когда клавиатура открывается?